# Registering Dropwizard configuration with Jersey 2 (HK2) DI

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, hk2

In my Dropwizard (1.2.4) application I'm having trouble injecting my Dropwizard configuration into classes that are instantiated by HK2. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind the configuration *instance*.

```
@Override
public void run(final DummyConfiguration conf, Environment env) {
    env.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(conf).to(DummyConfiguration.class);
        }
    })
}
```

Now you can `@Inject` the `DummyConfiguration` anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 2):

For dropwizard version 2.0.1:

```
@Override
public void run(final YourConfiguration conf, Environment env) throws Exception {
    env.jersey().getResourceConfig().register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(conf).to(YourConfiguration.class);
            // bind other classes
        }
    });

    // register resources
}
```