# In dropwizard, what is the best way to access configuration object anywhere in the application

Tags: dropwizard

In dropwizard, what are the options to make the configuration object being accessible in the application (not just resource object)? Thanks.

```
public class TestConfig extends Configuration {
    @JsonProperty String test;
}

public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application<TestConfig> {
    @Override
    public void run(TestConfig configuration, Environment environment) {
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026270/2587435

Comment: Would this work for normal class? I tried, it did not work for me.